# Typedef enum in C++

Tags: c++, variables, enums, typedef, member

I have one typedef like this

```
typedef enum
{
ONE = 01,
TWO = 02,
THREE = 03
}number_t;
```

I just defined one member variable as
number_t m_number;

so if I return m_number in any other functions what will be returned either ONE or TWO or THREE ?

Comment: This is C syntax, change it to `enum number_t { ONE = ... };` or even better `enum class number_t { ONE = ... };`

Comment: _if I return m_number in any other functions what will be returned_ -- Undefined behaviour as you didn't initialize m_number.

Comment: yes you are right.I am new to C++ coding so how can I initialize that m_number

Comment: @zett42 it's C++ syntax as well. But the type alias is mostly redundant indeed.

Comment: Caution: you're in for a shock when you get to `08`, even more so if you skip to `010`. Don't use leading zeroes on integer literals unless you really intend to count in octal.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't initialise the variable, it has an *indeterminate value*.

Thus it could be one of the integers that maps to `ONE`, `TWO` or `THREE`, or any other value.

It's not, in itself, wrong for an `enum` object to have a value that doesn't map to the enumerator, so that isn't a big problem. However, you cannot legally evaluate an indeterminate value, so you won't be able to safely observe this object until you assign it a value.

As an aside, you're in for a shock when you get to `08`, and even more so if you skip to `010`. Don't use leading zeroes on integer literals unless you really intend to count in octal.

Here's what you ought to do:

```
enum number_t
{
   ONE   = 1,
   TWO   = 2,
   THREE = 3
};

number_t number = ONE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like any other local variable, if it isn't initialized by your code then the content will be whatever is on the stack and in this case completely random.

If you want to be sure what the value is going to be then intialise it before use, add to your enum something like:

```
NUMBER_NOT_SET = 0
```

Then on entry to your function:

number_t m_number = NUMBER_NOT_SET;

Comment: _"the content will be whatever is on the stack"_ Not necessarily. The value is indeterminate and does not have to come from whatever is on the stack.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, granted, thats the text book definition, however on 99% of the compilers I have used this is the case.

Comment: @SP​​​​​​​​​​​​latten: I'm curious how you measured/determined that.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, years of experience since 1987, using various compilers on various platforms.   All local variables are created on the stack, if a value is not supplied then the contents of the stack are used.

Comment: I'm asking how you determined that it was the contents of the stack that you saw, rather than simply interdeterminate values from elsewhere. Did you examine the assembly of the program and the raw contents of the virtual memory space? I'm asking because for a simple variable like this, more often than not, your object won't even be _on_ the stack.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, as I said, local variables are created on the stack, if they are not initialised then the content of the variable will be whatever is on the stack, where else would it come from?

Comment: Ehm, in a register, or entirely optimised away into the semantics of the program? As you know from your years of experience since 1987, C++ is an abstraction, not a one-to-one mapping of lines-of-code to machine instructions. Find me the local variables on the stack in this example: https://godbolt.org/g/XXAyk4